# java: Bad Time with methods, not returning what it´s supposed too.

Tags: java, variables, methods, instance

I´ve been debugging this for hours now. Detecting collision. this code bellow works fine.

```
while (numberOfTurns >= 0)                                      
            {   
        GObject collision = getElementAt(ball.getX(),ball.getY());
        }
```

It will get any graphical object the ball collides with on screen and return it. However, this is not how I want to design the program. But instead make a seperate method for collision detection, like bellow:

```
    while (numberOfTurns >= 0)                                      
        {   
        getCollidingObject();
        }
```

Here is the method, it just returns itself

```
private GObject getCollidingObject()
{       
    return getElementAt (ball.getX(),ball.getY());
}
```

then I assign it to this private instance variable

```
private GObject collider = getCollidingObject();
```

But!!! it does not work, it just returns null. the first code snippet i posted works fine... anyone knows what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you're assigning the return value of `getCollidingObject()` to a *private instance variable*. With the code you posted, that call is being made *once* on construction of your object, not every time you want the result. Try:

```
while (numberOfTurns >= 0)                                      
    {   
    GObject collision = getCollidingObject();
    }
```

Comment: but the getCollidingObject() method is within a while loop, so it should update the instance variable accordingly

Comment: `getCollidingObject()`, as you have shown it, does not change the value of any instance variable because there's no assignment to any instance variable.

Comment: disregard my previous post, Your correct, it works as supposed when I assign it to a GObject inside the while loop. Obviously an misunderstanding of the mechanics on my part..

Comment: I think you may be envisioning a situation where the return value of `getCollidingObject()` is somehow "attached" to the `collider` instance variable. Java doesn't work this way, and the assignment to `collider` only happens once, when your object is constructed. Calling `getCollidingObject()` later gives you the opportunity to use the return value some other way (or even assign it to `collider`, if you like).